# Why does my data change into NaN in Task4?

Tags: python, pandas

Why does my data change into NaN in task 4? I also tried using .loc[], but that still doesn't work. I need to be able to use the numbers.

```
dec6 = pd.read_csv('coinmarketcap_06122017.csv', header=0)
market_cap_raw = dec6[['id', 'market_cap_usd']]
print(market_cap_raw.describe())
#print(market_cap_raw)
market_cap_raw.count()

#Task 3
cap = market_cap_raw.query('market_cap_usd > 0')
cap.count()
print(cap.describe())

#Task 4
cap10 = cap.head(10).reindex(index=cap['id'])
print(cap10.describe())
```

Result:

```
       market_cap_usd
count    1.144000e+03
mean     4.861599e+08
std      6.713982e+09
min      1.200000e+01
25%      7.513858e+05
50%      6.856627e+06
75%      4.043108e+07
max      1.862130e+11
       market_cap_usd
count    1.144000e+03
mean     4.861599e+08
std      6.713982e+09
min      1.200000e+01
25%      7.513858e+05
50%      6.856627e+06
75%      4.043108e+07
max      1.862130e+11
       market_cap_usd
count             0.0
mean              NaN
std               NaN
min               NaN
25%               NaN
50%               NaN
75%               NaN
max               NaN
```

The last print results in NaN.

Comment: what is the expected result, and what are you seeing?

Comment: I want to "Calculate the percentage of market capitalization for each coin using assign() and assign it to cap10 again."       
       market_cap_usd
count    1.144000e+03
mean     4.861599e+08
std      6.713982e+09
min      1.200000e+01
25%      7.513858e+05
50%      6.856627e+06
75%      4.043108e+07
max      1.862130e+11
       market_cap_usd
count             0.0
mean              NaN
std               NaN
min               NaN
25%               NaN
50%               NaN
75%               NaN
max               NaN

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `head(...)` after `reindex(...)`.

`cap10 = cap.head(10).reindex(index=cap['id'])` means you extract the first 10 rows then apply the full length of index later. Change them to `cap10 = cap.reindex(index=cap['id']).head(10)`.

Answer (score 0):

The re_index() method is causing the data to change to NaN.